# array_search function doesn't check first value

Tags: php, arrays, search

I have an array which gives me correct results when I print it, for example:

```
[0] => info@mail.com,
[1] => 0909,
[2] => info@mail.com22,
[3] => 0909
```

Now, when I want to check if info@mail.com is in the array it gives me an error that the value doesnt exist in this array, but when I try for example info@mail.com22 it gives the correct result.

This is a little part of the code:
$user is the word I want to search, $arrayname is the array.

```
if (array_search(strtolower($user),array_map('strtolower',$arrayname))){
//value exist
}
else{
//value does not exist
}
```

Now info@mail.com doesn't exist it says, while info@mail.com22 does exist.

Who has any idea?

Comment: The cause is actually in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php). *"This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the return value of this function."*

Comment: Because it returns zero

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`array_search` returns the index of the value that is found. When you search for the first item it returns 0. which is also means `false`. change your code so that it reads

```
if (false !== array_search(strtolower($user),array_map('strtolower',$arrayname))){
```

an alternative method would be to use `in_array`

```
if(in_array(strtolower($user),array_map('strtolower',$arrayname))){
```

Answer (score 0):

I simply use `is_numeric`

```
if (is_numeric(array_search(strtolower($user), $arrayname)) {
    /* do something */
}
```